# How can I make cookies' 'key: value' array after getting their value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, key-value

I want to get specific cookies and make a 'key: value' array,
I already have the names/keys of the cookies I want.

this is what I tried:

```
var cookiesNames= ["cookie1","cookie2","cookie3"];
var cookiesList = {};

function getCookie(cname) {
  let name = cname + "=";
  let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  let cvalue= [];

  for(let i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        cvalue = [c.substring(name.length, c.length)];
 // Creates a key: value list
      cookiesList[cname] = c.value;
     }
  }
}

//  Gets all the cookies' names from the list 
for (var key in cookiesNames) {
 getCookie(cname);
}
```

When I run this at the console I get an error saying "cname is not defined"
Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: It should be `getCookie(key)` inside the last `for..in` loop

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main issues with your code:

1. In the last loop:

```
//  Gets all the cookies' names from the list 
for (var key in cookiesNames) {
 getCookie(cname);
}
```

a. You're iterating with a `for in` loop which will iterate the indices so the `key` will be `0, 1, 2 ...`. You should use a `for of` loop which will iterate over the items in the array.
b. You're passing `cname` to the array, which is `undefined`. You should pass the key like: `getCookie(key)`

2. there is a typo in this line:

```
cookiesList[cname] = c.value;
```

It should be `cookiesList[cname] = cvalue`. *without the dot*

Also, this code will get the cookie value inside an array like:

```
{
  cookie1: ["cookie value"]
}
```

if you want it as a key-value pair, remove the square brackets in this line: `cvalue = [c.substring(name.length, c.length)];`